# How can I generate the same VSIX file as the one in vscode extensions if I had to git clone the whole project and use "vsce package" to generate it?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, vsix

To provide more details for my question:

I actually had my vscode installed in the laptop which is for work only, and due to access constraint, I can't install any extensions within vscode nor any manual downloads thru microsoft marketplace. So I GitHub clone(https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python.git) the Microsoft python vscode extension project and tried to use node.js to generate("vsce package") the VSIX by myself, so that I can manually install this VSIX. And I did managed generate the VSIX file, but it has only a size of 400K, which is far much less than the original one with size 40M.

So I wonder where did I do wrong, or is there anyone kind enough to let me know what should I do to generate a complete VSIX as the one downloaded?

Thanks!

Comment: To add: the one downloaded from market place is with the name "ms-python.python-2020.4.76186.vsix", but the one I generated with node.js cmd "vsce package" is with the name "python-2020.6.0-dev.vsix".

Comment: You can't download from the marketplace website? Why not?

Comment: As I said -- due to access constraint -- including Internet access, I just can't download it from marketplace -- but luckily I can git clone so I can have the source code.

Comment: It makes no sense. If you're not allowed to directly download prebuilt .vsix from the marketplace, can't you download it on a different machine and then somehow transfer to the laptop?

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't. Due to security reasons, my company had abandoned any outside unknown files. And this is exactly why I have to re-generate a VSIX file in this way -- because the VSIX file is also considered to be "unknown".

Answer (score 3):

According to the docs for the vscode python extension, there are a few additional build steps you have to run to create a local build of the vsix:

https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md#development-process

```
> npm install -g vsce
# Perform the next steps in the vscode-python folder.
> npm ci
> python3 -m pip --disable-pip-version-check install -t ./pythonFiles/lib/python --no-cache-dir --implementation py --no-deps --upgrade -r requirements.txt
> python3 -m pip --disable-pip-version-check install -t ./pythonFiles/lib/python/old_ptvsd --no-cache-dir --implementation py --no-deps --upgrade 'ptvsd==4.3.2'
# For python 3.6 and lower use this command to install the debugger
> python3 -m pip --disable-pip-version-check install -t ./pythonFiles/lib/python --no-cache-dir --implementation py --no-deps --upgrade --pre debugpy
# For python 3.7 and greater use this command to install the debugger
> python3 -m pip --disable-pip-version-check install -r build/debugger-install-requirements.txt
> python3 ./pythonFiles/install_debugpy.py
> npm run clean
> npm run package # This step takes around 10 minutes.
```

This won't necessarily be the same build as a release build, which has additional requirements [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python/blob/master/.github/release_plan.md).

Comment: Thanks Brianc! But I failed at the very beginning at "npm ci", which is due to it can't find my python.exe (because I can't change the #PATH or any ENV related area). I know I am being annoying, but for security reason, my company abandoned us from bring any personal files nor any install any softwares... So I can only copy my python zip from somewhere sharefolder and unzip it on my local drive, and run python with the full path. -- I wonder -- is there another way of running "npm ci" instead?

Comment: I've managed to overcome this python error thing, but I've encountered into another one: "You need to install the latest version of Visual Studio including the Desktop development with C++ workload"... So, is it really necessary to run "npm ci"?